# how do I use Financial.NPV() function in c#

Tags: c#, math, finance

I have to use NPV function for Financial calculation. I did some researches but I was confused about how to add it into my c# project.

people say that; `Just add Financial.dll to the references in your project. The functions are provided as static methods on a Financial class in the System.Numerics namespace`

I added System.Numerics namespace but I couldnt reach to NPV function. Where can I find the Financial.dll file?

Thanks

Comment: Check your project properties, to see if the project is targeted to a different version of .net Framework (e.g. Client Profile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access it just like any other classes containing functions:

```
double npvResult = Financial.Npv(rate, flows);
```

(Pulled from [here](http://ricardocovo.com/2013/01/14/financial-functions-in-net-c/))